# UIPageViewController - animated transition to next view controller mixes up with orientation change

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am developing an app that uses UIPageViewController. In the `UIPageViewController` subclass at some point I am setting the next view controller like this:

```
guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
guard let nextViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) else { return }

self.setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: { (finished) in         
            // some finishing work
})
```

The app supports both portrait and landscape. The transition to the next view controller is animated. When that animation starts, if an orientation change starts after that, at the end of both animations there will be two partially visible view controllers instead of just the next one.

I guess that it calculates the offset before the transition to the next view controller starts, then starts the animation with this offset, then rotates and resizes the views, but doesn't recalculate the offset. Or something like this. Does anyone have an idea how to fix or workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

I've only done a quick initial test of this, but it *may* do the job for you.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first {

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            // nothing here
        }) { [unowned self] _ in
            self.setViewControllers([currentViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: { (finished) in
                // some finishing work
            })
        }

    }

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

}
```

Depending on what *"some finishing work"* entails, it might get a little tricky... probably need to test the `finished` state.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but I still have the issue sometimes.